# Run “WebSphere application server” and “WebSphere Process Server” in a single machine

Tags: websphere, websphere-process-server

In our project we have installed both the “WebSphere application server” and “WebSphere Process Server” in a single machine. But we are unable to run both the server at a same time.

WebSphere Process Server is mounted on top of WebSphere Application Server, so while we are running the process server the **default WebSphere application server instance is starting with the process server**.  So after that if we try to start the **separately installed WebSphere application server**, we are getting error that **one instance is already running**. Please suggest how to avoid this conflict and run both the process and application server in the single machine?

Both are using the same port. We already renamed the server name of the separately installed WebSphere application server with “server2” and Process Server’s application server name is “server1”

Please share your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You need to create separate profile. You don't have to install WAS first, or install it again, if you don't want. You may use Profile Management Tool from your installation to create new separate profile for WAS (choose Application Server profile type, not Process Server).

If you want complete separation e.g different versions (like vX of WPS and vY of WAS), or different fix pack level, you will need to do full separate WAS install.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere Process Server extends Websphere Application Server (WAS), so you should install WAS first. Websphere Process Server (WPS) install should be made on top. When installation is complete you will be able to create WAS and WPS profiles on this machine. WPS profile always include WAS libraries and can be managed exactly the same way as WAS.
If you want separate servers, you should create two profiles, one for WAS and one for WPS.
You will be able to manage them separately.